# Problem with get back to the previous menu telebot on python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

I try to create a navigation so it allows my telegram bot users to get back to the previous menu by clicking button but I should press this button twice for it to work correctly Here is my code

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    zoom = types.KeyboardButton('Zoom')
    google = types.KeyboardButton('Google meet')

    markup.add(zoom, google)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, {0.first_name}!'.format(message.from_user),reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def bot_message(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Zoom':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            back = types.KeyboardButton('Назад в стартовое меню')
            markup.add(back)
            #bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Enter please Zoom meeting id: ',reply_markup=markup)
            msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Введите Zoom meeting id:\nВ формате:78021230370', reply_markup=markup)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, meeting_id)
        elif message.text == 'Google meet':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            back = types.KeyboardButton('Назад в стартовое меню')
            markup.add(back)
            # bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Enter please Zoom meeting id: ',reply_markup=markup)
            msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Введите Google meet link:\nВ формате - https://meet.google.com/smi-vodj-nfe', reply_markup=markup)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, google_link)

def google_link(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    back = types.KeyboardButton('Назад в стартовое меню')
    markup.add(back)
    meeting_link1 = message.text
    if message.text == 'Назад в стартовое меню':
        details1.clear()
        details.clear()
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, start)
    elif len(meeting_link1) < 36 or len(meeting_link1) > 36:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите корректный google link:\nВ формате - https://meet.google.com/smi-vodj-nfe', reply_markup=markup)
        meeting_link = message.text
        print(meeting_link)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, google_link)
    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите google email:', reply_markup=markup)
        print(meeting_link1)
        details1.append(message.from_user.username)
        details1.append(meeting_link1)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, google_email)
```

I have tried different approaches but it still doesn't work properly how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it is competent solution, but I use it in my bot, and it works.

1. You can try to decorate your handlers with this:

   ```
   def NextStepHandler(function):
       def _functionHandler(message: telebot.types.Message):
           # if not text message, continue handler process
           if not message.text:
               return function(message)

           # checking if message is command
           # which means it looks like this: '/start'
           # if incorrect, continue handler process
           command = re.fullmatch(r'^/\w+$', message.text)

           if not command:
               return function(message)

           # get command text
           command = command.string[1:]

           # checking all BOT handlers
           # if there is handler for command received in message - force method call
           [handler["function"].__call__(message) for handler in BOT.message_handlers
           if command in handler["filters"]["commands"]]

       return _functionHandler
   ```

and then do this:

```
@NextStepHandler
def google_link(message):
    # your code
```

to your next step handler.

2. Second option is create casual method which does the same as decorator above:

   ```
   def execute(message: telebot.types.Message) -> None:
       if not message.text:
           return

       command = re.fullmatch(r'^/\w+$', message.text)

       if not command:
           return

       command = command.string[1:]

       [handler["function"].__call__(message) for handler 
        in BOT.message_handlers if command in handler["filters"]["commands"]]
   ```

but you should call it manually at the beginng of every next step handler you register:

```
    def google_link(message):
        execute(message)
        # your code
```

Notice that the `BOT` variable is your TeleBot instance `telebot.Telebot(...)`.

UPD. What the purpose of using above:

- when next step handler, in your case it is `google_link` method, accepts message from user, primarily it checks if the user's message is a command in decorator `NextStepHandler` or manually called function `execute`. If the message *is* a command, the function that is responsible for processing this command is forced to be called and handler stops doing next steps. If message is not a command, handler continue its work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).